# How to query mysql database within an existing script?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an entry page for a script, which needs to query a MySQL database. It will be located at something like `domain.com/e.php`, and `domain.com` is an already existing and professional script which uses a connection to the database (I am not sure how this is done, but I enter dbname, user, password, hostname as variables in a config file in something like `domain.com/admin/config.php` of the script).

I have a code like this which is working:

```
<?php
$param=$_GET['m'];
$param=str_replace("-", " ", $param);
$param=ucwords($param); 
echo $param; 
?>
```

This would take `domain.com/e.php?m=sunny-leone` and print out "Sunny Leone" on `e.php` page, which is what is needed.

I now need to run the following query on a MySQL database:

`SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE another_column_name='$param'`

With this I am wondering if I need to connect to the database from this certain file, or do I already have this connection in place (by using the above mentioned script)?

Also, I am not sure if somebody could do that, but how would I get this to work? I want to do the above query and store it in a variable like $query, so I can using in further parts of the script.

Basically, do I need to add something like this and then do the query, or not necessarily (just do the query without connecting?)?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user_name";
password = "password_here";
$dbname = "db_name_here";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: You could include / require the config.php file and use the connection there. But unless the database connection is available elsewhere for your script then you do indeed need to connect before you can execute the query.

Comment: refer this tutorial: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: Ok. So basically, if a person clicks on a links like this and goes to domain.com/e.php, this does not have anything to do with the rest of the script, and databse connection needs to be made in every single file like this? I can find most of the info for working on this on the Net, but I am not sure about this part, and I want to do the best and the most minimal code (like including whats in config.php would be good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Find out whether the existing system uses any common CMS or Framework packages. If it's a CMS like Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal, you would probably be best off doing it as a CMS page. If it's using a Framework like Laravel, Symphony or Zend, then you would likely want to use the Framework's MVC and write a controller class (at the very least). Either way, you'll be making use of the existing platform to reduce the amount of unnecessary code you have to write - ie you won't need to connect to the DB, and you'll be able to use the platform's database object models, templating system, etc and re-use the page layout from the rest of the site with very little work.

If you go down this route, the final solution will vary wildly depending on which platform the system is written using; you'll need to get further advice once you know more about the system (I suggest starting a new SO question at that point if you need more help).

In the event that you decide not to do this, and just write a simple raw PHP page without referencing the original platform, then yes, your basic code sample is a good starting point. Yes, you will need to connect to the DB for yourself, and if you need to do things like output a page using the site's standard theme, then you'll need to re-implement that from scratch.

You haven't touched in the question on what your actual query code is likely to look like, but you should also beware of security issues such as SQL injection with using `$_GET` variables directly in a query (or even just outputting them back to the user as in your example).